# MongoDB: Updating element in array always results in first element updated

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

TL;DR : Updating element in array always results in first element updated and results differ based on property name of key used in find params
Playground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/-4kGZnxa-WA

I want to update an object in a array and I am using 2 of the object properties to find the object then using $set operator with array.$.updateProperty to update the object

Here is the working playground link of what I want to do:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/dswt8vuzJMc

But I cant reproduce the same when I change a single property name (both in database as well as find parameter) , from the above example I changed property `foo` to `trackID` but then only the first element in array is always updated

Playground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/-4kGZnxa-WA

It seems weird as I assumed the property name shouldn't matter as long as it used the same in find params too and its not  a keyword like `_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `update` is very close.  You need to use `"$elemMatch"` to identify the specific array position where both conditions match.

N.B.: [`$`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) will only `update` the *first matching* array element.  If you want to update *all* array elements, use [`$[]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/), and if you want to update *all matching* array elements, using [`"arrayFilters"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) with `$[<indentifier>]` is convenient.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("62f11e22d99c79532de6ff7f"),
  "jobs": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "trackID": 0,
      "name": "kaisen_track-0_h264_1080p"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "jobs.$.status": "Done"
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PVzgOWvNJtA).

Comment: Thanks , works perfect but I am still confused why did the operation worked on this playground (working playground mentioned in question): https://mongoplayground.net/p/dswt8vuzJMc 
The only difference I see with both the playgrounds in question is the property name , am I missing any other difference ?

Comment: @Solaris I'm a little confused too.  I don't know the internals of `mongod` so I can only speculate.  By some means (?), in your original query ,`mongod` determines the array element of each match independently (?) and if they both happen to be the same, then `$` works as a valid array position?  It's actually a little scary since if the mongoplayground prototyping worked (by some lucky/unlucky occurrence), there's no guarantee (unlikely really) that the luck would carry over to your real/production system. That's why learning the proper query syntax, here `"$elemMatch"`, is so important.

Comment: Might be a bug or unhandled checks on necessary syntax , anyhow the proper syntax `$elemMatch` is working consistently as expected so will stick to it, thanks for the help